# Can I pipe a large file into ftp connection?

Tags: linux, ftp

I need to create a very large tar file (25GB) and transfer it to another site using `ftp`.

Rather than first creating the tar file and then transferring it, I wonder if its possible to pipe the output from tar into `ftp` (or `ncftp`) and transfer it immediately without saving the tar file locally first.

I'm using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Regular FTP or can it be SFTP?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Regular FTP.

Comment: A similar question and its answer using `curl`: https://serverfault.com/a/934153/437279 . The answer involves an SFTP server, but replacing the protocol to `ftp://` will simply work for an FTP server. But as for a large source file... you should consider compresing the file beforehand; FTP protocol does not support data comppression to reduce the amount of data to be transmitted. If SFTP is available, through SSH's compression capability, you can choose to compress the source file during transmission.

Comment: In case of a communication glitch, piping the tar result will mean redoing everything. Using a restartable method might be safer.